# How do sites like Google, Yahoo, etc store their user/pass?

Tags: database, scalability, storage

How do big websites store the millions of user/pass combinations? I'm asking about how things are stored in the database - or do they even use a database? How do they scan through the millions of entries almost instantly?

Comment: Millions of records is nothing if the table is properly indexed.

Comment: Is there something you are looking for that my answer has not provided?  If not please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashed index.  If you use a numeric, unique userid you can assume few collisions (if set up correctly) and hash indexes are your best bet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

And yes, they do use databases.  Typically multiple load balanced servers.  See this question for ideas on load balancing for SQL server as there are multiple approaches:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761502/sql-server-load-balancing

One popular way to load balance is called "federating" by Microsoft, but it pretty much spreads the query request and lets it be serviced by multiple servers (afaik).